# FaceBook php api get realtime updates?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, real-time

Hi i am trying to use Realtime updates in facebook application, 
My application basically backs up the user's photos, messages and friendlist, i want when a user adds a new friend data on server should also be updated, when a user adds a new album the most recent album should be downloaded automatically to my server
I got this code from [github-php](https://github.com/facebook/real-time/tree/master/samples/php) , but dont know what next?

Please help if anyone has done with real time updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to query the code after certain interval which you can use AJAX to update the page without refresh. 
There is no automatic updates without query the information every time.

Comment: I thought the asker was talking about this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/ So there's a way to implement real time updates and your answer is wrong.

Comment: thanks for update, I will go through the documentation to explore more

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe using one module and you specify a callback url during the subscription... you only subscribe once and you get updates for everyone who has authorized your app.  The updates come to you via the callback url and its very crappy info that basically tells you that you have to go back and query fb to get the full details.